# feed icon link is wrong in firefox

Tags: bug, status-norepro, icon, feeds, firefox

the askubuntu.com site has a rss/atom feed which is available via the rss icon in the awesomebar of firefox. if you click on that icon, the page firefox wants to open is [feed://http//askubuntu.com/feeds](http://feed://http//askubuntu.com/feeds).

as you can see this is formatted wrong as it should be https://askubuntu.com/feeds

if you click on the feed icons of opera and ie they are going to the right address, so it's firefox only.

Comment: `<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed of recent questions" href="/feeds">` -- I'd rather assume this is a bug in Firefox. Also, it works as expected in my Firefox 3.6.12 -- What version are you using?

Comment: Are you using any extensions which may be contributing to this?

Comment: Even in safe-mode (3.6.12) I can reproduce it. In my vm I can't reproduce it. It might be caused by the stupid corporate proxy.

Answer (score 1):

We can't reproduce this.